# Multiple outcomes in implicit navigation with JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

Please I am missing a point here. How can I handle a request with multiple outcomes in JSF 2.0 using the implicit navigation 
For example using the explicit navigation I can write the following:

```xml
 <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/products/DeleteItem.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>itemDeleted</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/products/Success.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>itemNotExist</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/products/Failure.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

However How can I achieve the same thing with the implicit navigation, I have tried the following :

```
    <h:link value="Delete a Product" outcome="Success" />
```

only one case is mentioned but I want to forward either to Success.xhtml or Failure.xhtml depending on the outcome.

Here a some additional information for the implicit navigation.

**Managed bean:**

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DeletionBean {  
@EJB
private app.session.ProductFacade ejbProductFacade;  


private int id=0;


public DeletionBean() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

 public String deleteProduct(){
    String result;
    result=ejbProductFacade.deleteItem(id);

    if(result.equals("success"))
    {
        status="Successfully performed"; //msg to be shown 

        return "product/DeleteItem";
    }

     else  return "product/Failure";
} 

}
```

**Form**:

```
<h:form>
               <table border="1" width="5" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

                         <tr>
                            <td> Product ID </td>

                            <td>

                               <h:inputText id="pid" size="10"  value="#{deletionBean.id}" title="Product ID" required="true" requiredMessage="Product ID required"/>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                         <tr>

                            <td colspan="2"> 
                            <h:commandLink  value="Delete" action="#{deletionBean.deleteProduct}" />
                            </td>

                         </tr>

                </table>

            </h:form>
```

**Current error message:**

> Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/product/DeleteItem.xhtml' for action '#{deletionBean.deleteProduct}' with outcome 'product/Failure'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you'll perform an `action` method to delete your product, you should make your method return the desired outcome. Using JSF 2, there's no need of using outcome ids anymore, even you can declare them in your *faces-config.xml* file, JSF ties a provided outcome with a specific page:

```xhtml
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.deleteProduct(product)}" 
    value="Delete product" />
```

```java
public String deleteProduct(Product p){
    //Try to delete the product and return "products/xxx", 
    //which will be converted to "/contextname/products/xxx.xhtml"
    try{
        daoService.delete(p);
        return "/products/Success";
    catch(Exception e){
        return "/products/Failure";
    }
}
```

That will **POST** the server and behaves like an HTML form submit button (that's why it's called `commandLink`). Nevertheless if you want just to perform a **GET** to an specific view, you can use its view id in the outcome:

```
<h:link value="Go to success doing nothing" 
    outcome="/products/Success" />
```

**See also:**

[Implicit navigation in JSF 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitNavigation)

Comment: Thanks @Xtreme Biker for the quick response I have made the modification as you mention but I am getting the following error message

Comment: Try with full path. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Xtreme Biker for the quick response I have made the modification as you mention but I am getting the following error message. **Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/product/DeleteItem.xhtml' for action '#{deletionBean.deleteProduct}' with outcome 'product/Failure' **

Comment: Try with `/products/Failure`. The path has to match exactly the page you're looking for. If you're navigating from `DeleteItem.xhtml`, `Failure` should be enough, as the outcome is resolved with the relative path.

Comment: Thanks once more for the reply, this time it works. From now on i will consider integrating implicit navigation in my projects, the feature is cool.